# Why instead IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2.1 I'm creating System.String com object?

Tags: powershell

here's what I have :

```
PS C:\Users\user> $idi=New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2.1
PS C:\Users\user> $idi|get-member


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparab..
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int co..
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringCompari.....
 ....
 ....
```

Here's the [documentation of the IMAPI things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365380(v=vs.85).aspx#methods) and System.String is part of the .net framework.

To me looks like MS messed up something with CLSIDs.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking at, it is not $idi nor does it work at all when I try it.  Powershell is ... different.  Try `New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2.1 | Get-Member` instead.

Comment: @HansPassant - In this way the output is different ! And I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from Comment to Answer here as I can't format the output properly.

Get-Member -InputObject $idi returns:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{27354130-7f64-5b0f-8f00-5d77afbe261e}

Name                   MemberType            Definition
----                   ----------            ----------
Item                   ParameterizedProperty string Item (int) {get}
Count                  Property              int Count () {get}
IsSupportedEnvironment Property              bool IsSupportedEnvironment () {get}
```

which appears correct and Count/IsSupportedEnvironment correctly identify that I have no optical drives in my laptop.